# Swift Compiler Error Group

Tags: swift, xcode, compiler-errors, certificate, provisioning-profile

Sorry to post this again. But I really got lost in solving this bug in my Xcode. I am using Xcode Version 8.0 swift 3 , I have got this error when building the project:
Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11, and it shows me in the storyboards the code in black color for a while. Also, there is a notification says An internal error occurred, Source editor functionality is limited, attempting to restore, Report a Bug.

I have searched a lot and most things I found about building, cleaning, reopening the project. Also, I tried to uncheck and recheck the Automatically managed signing for my project.

I hope to hear from you the best solution for my problem
waiting for your replay greatest coders

Comment: uninstall and reinstall xcode if you think really bug to  the xcode

Comment: I install Xcode 8.1 and the same problem still fires

Comment: Did the project work in Xcode 7?

Comment: I don't have Xcode 7 @wottle

Comment: So this is a brand new project and you have never been able to build the project successfully in Xcode 8?

Comment: No I was able to build it before. But when I start preparing my app for submitting it in Apple Store this error came out.

Comment: @wottle do you suggest for me to change the version of Xcode ?

Comment: No, I was just trying to isolate what had changed between when you could build the project and when you couldn't.  So you were trying to get your app ready for app store submission.  Can you build successfully for development still (i.e. directly to a test device)?  If not, I'm thinking that somehow the files got corrupted.  If you have a source repository (you should) I would try to check out an old revision and see if you can get that to work.  I do not believe this has anything to do with code signing.

Comment: I just figure out that this error only fires in two Cocoa touch classes, these files have the same code. I can't run it in test device. And when I delete these files my app work well. Also, I recreate my app in new project and when I copy the code from these files the error fires again !!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I went to the 'Debug Session' window and saw I had type conversion issues. I was trying to determine is an object was a Set and needed to evaluate it as a Set<String>.

Not sure if that'll help you, but check out the 'Debug Session' window to see which view controller class has the issue and what it is.